# Reading 101 objects from Pymongo cursor runs instantly--reading 102 objects from Pymongo cursor hangs

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm a little bamboozled by this behavior. I have a Pymongo query that fetches one field from all records in a collection (the collection contains 1 million records):

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.holidays

serials = db.christmas.find({}, {
  '_id': 0,
  'gifts': 1, # this field is an integer
})
```

I then transform this generator of dictionaries (each with a single key) into a list of `gifts` values with the following, which runs instantly:

```py
l = []
for idx, i in enumerate(serials):
  l.append(i['gifts'])
  if idx > 99: break
```

However, if I change that last line to `if idx > 100: break`, the process hangs and never returns. Does anyone know what might cause this behavior? All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Don't enumerate it; put a `.limit(99)` on the find instead.

Comment: Also c.f. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-batches re why 101 matters

Comment: @BellyBuster Interesting, thanks for the link. I thought Pymongo fetched additional data batches for the user, but perhaps not. My goal is to fetch the `gifts` attribute from all of the records--is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Just don't enumerate it and let the cursor do it's thing.

Comment: Interesting--setting the batch_size key word arg manually `serials = db.christmas.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'gifts': 1}, batch_size=2**8)` allows for _much_ faster conversion from cursor to list...

Comment: Where is the driver documentation for `find` and what is the correct usage for iterating the results?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason I couldn't reproduce your issue. Maybe it's a version issue (I'm python 3.8.5; pymongo 3.11.0, mongodb 4.2.10). I loaded up a sample collection with 1M (albeit small) documents and this completed in less than 2.5 seconds on a stock PC. If you get different results, maybe try upgrading.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Uncomment the next line to load the sample data
# db.mycollection.insert_many([{'gifts': x} for x in range(1000000)]) 

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

l = [x['gifts'] for x in db.mycollection.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'gifts': 1})]

print(f'{(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()} Seconds')
print(len(l))
```

prints:

```
2.383489 Seconds
1000000
```